# How can I apply "ID" for the sweetAlert.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm trying to apply the id to the sweet alert select element. I only know how to add class but I was trying to find how to add ID also in the off.docs. but unable to find it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you talking about the `customClass` property, and you want something similar, only with ID? If that is the case - Why do you need it?

Comment: Yes with ID. I need to initialize other plugin which require ID

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/xkgwcbh7/2/

Comment: yes that's it :) Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to directly add Id to Sweetalert modal.

However we can add Class to Sweetalert modal with:

`customClass: 'class-name',`

There is also a work around to add Id to different elements in Sweetalert by adding a onOpen function:

`onOpen: function() { $('.swal2-modal').attr('id','modal_id');$('.swal2-content').attr('id','modalcontent_id');}`

Answer (score 0):

you can make it, in `sweetalert2` , I hope would be help you.

```
      // # in this example result -> id="txt-note" 
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Ingrese el contenido de la nota",
        input: "text",
        inputAttributes: {
          id: "txt-note",
        },
        customClass: {
          container: "modal-create-note",
        },
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Crear",
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        preConfirm: (textoNota) => {
          console.log(textoNota)
          
        },
        allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading(),
      }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
```

```js
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Ingrese el contenido de la nota",
        input: "text",
        inputAttributes: {
          id: "txt-note",
        },
        customClass: {
          container: "modal-create-note",
        },
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Crear",
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        preConfirm: (textoNota) => {
          console.log(textoNota)
          
        },
        allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading(),
      }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://sweetalert2.github.io/styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```